# terraform vsphere official provider, creating vm with ovf_deploy

Tags: terraform-provider

I'm a Korean worker who uses terraform codes to provision virtual machines in vcenter by using official terraform vsphere provider.

I am provisioning vms with ovf templates currently, so I tried to configure 'remote_ovf_url' of the datastore path which has ovf file.

But it seems that 'remote_ovf_url' argument doesn't mean the vcenter's datastore folder path.

Is my guess right?. If it is not, how can I find the 'remote_url_path' of the datastore?

Does vsphere provider not support the creation of virtual machines through ovf files on vcenter's content library or datastore?

```
data "vsphere_datacenter" "datacenter" {
  name = "Datacenter"
}

data "vsphere_compute_cluster" "cluster" {
  name          = "새 클러스터"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "datastore1"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_host" "host" {
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name = "VM Network"
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
}

data "vsphere_ovf_vm_template" "ovf" {
  name = "terraform-ovf-vm"
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  host_system_id = data.vsphere_host.host.id
  datastore_id = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  # remote_ovf_url = "https://10.1.0.153/cls/data/293ed829-9178-4ee7-a0bf-8b57b216e423/linux-mint-2.ovf" # when export ovf, I copied its url
  # remote_ovf_url = "https://10.1.0.153/ui/data/properties/urn:vmomi:Folder:group-d1:8f6de25d-8ed0-4032-b90e-b762588f4801?properties=libraryTemplates" # developer tool's (F12) 
  remote_ovf_url = "https://10.1.0.153/ui/app/datastore;nav=s/urn:vmomi:Datastore:datastore-15:8f6de25d-8ed0-4032-b90e-b762588f4801/files/220707_2bae2c91-0496-484c-862b-313fa67022a6.ovf" # just entered the vcenter web ui and attached ovf file to '.../files/' 
} # I tried all of the tries above, but failed.

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = "terraform-vm-ha101"
  datacenter_id    = data.vsphere_datacenter.datacenter.id
  host_system_id   = data.vsphere_host.host.id
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id
  num_cpus         = 1
  memory           = 1024
  guest_id         = "otherLinux64Guest"
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.network.id
  }
 
  ovf_deploy {
    allow_unverified_ssl_cert = false
    remote_ovf_url            = data.vsphere_ovf_vm_template.ovf.remote_ovf_url
    disk_provisioning         = "thin"
    ip_protocol               = "IPV4"
    ip_allocation_policy      = "STATIC_MANUAL"
    ovf_network_map = {
      "Network 1" = data.vsphere_network.network.id
      "Network 2" = data.vsphere_network.network.id
    }
  }
  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 16
    thin_provisioned = false
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Terraform vSphere provider does support the creation of a virtual machine using OVF from a content library by using the [vsphere_virtual_machine resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine) with the [clone option](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#clone).

```
# Data source for vCenter Content Library
data "vsphere_content_library" "my_content_library" {
  name = "My Content Library"
}

# Data source for vCenter Content Library Item
data "vsphere_content_library_item" "my_ovf_item" {
  name       = "My OVF Item"
  type       = "ovf"
  library_id = data.vsphere_content_library.my_content_library.id
}

# Deploy a VM from OVF in Content Library
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm_from_ovf" {
  name                 = "VM from OVF"
  datastore_id         = data.vsphere_datastore.my_datastore.id
  resource_pool_id     = data.vsphere_resource_pool.my_resource_pool.id
  folder               = "folder/subfolder"
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 5
  
  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    size             = 16
    controller_type  = "scsi"
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_content_library_item.my_ovf_item.id
  }

  network_interface {
    network_id = data.vsphere_network.my_portgroup.id
  }
}
```

If you need to specify parameters to the OVF, you can use the [vApp option](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#vapp).